# Building Expression Tree Using a Parameter's Indexer

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

Given a class that has a property that is a Dictionary

```
public class Product
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get { return attributes; } }

    private Dictionary<string, string> attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

I want to be able to match products in a list of products based on criteria that are retrieved from a data store that are in the format of

```
Brand == Tyco
Color != Blue
```

My current approach is to construct an expression from the filter, and then pass that expression as the parameter to a LINQ `Where` method call like so

```
products = products.Where(myConstructedExpression);
```

where `myConstructedExpression` would normally be a lamda expression that looks like

```
p => p.Attributes[attribute] == value
```

I have assembled the following code for testing purposes, but it always fails the call to `lambda.Compile()` regardless of what I have tried for he left expression.

```
Dictionary<string, ExpressionType> expressionType = new Dictionary<string, ExpressionType>();
expressionType.Add("==", ExpressionType.Equal);
expressionType.Add("!=", ExpressionType.NotEqual);

string filter = "Brand == Tyco";
string[] fields = filter.Split(' ');
string attribute = fields[0];
string op = fields[1];
string value = fields[2];

Product product = new Product();
product.Attributes.Add("Brand", "Tyco"); 

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
var left = /***** THIS IS WHAT I AM FAILING TO CONSTRUCT PROPERLY ********/
var right = Expression.Constant(value);
var operation = Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType[op], left, right);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(operation, parameter);

var result = lambda.Compile()(product);
```

**Questions**

1. Is this even a reasonable approach, and, if so,
2. How do I construct the left expression?

Comment: Why are you trying to use expression tress? Why isn't the lambda enough?

Comment: Because I have no idea what the filter is going to be. Specifically, I don't know what the operator will be. I have to decide at runtime if it's going to be ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=, etc. And, afaik, I can't pass an arbitrary operator to a lambda expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to get `p => p.Attributes["Brand"] <someoperator> "Tyco"`, you can do this.

The "trick", to work with indexed types, is to use their [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item.aspx) property (you could also work with the `get_item` method)

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
Expression left = Expression.Property(parameter, "Attributes");
left = Expression.Property(left, "Item", new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(attribute) });
```

**EDIT**

the version with the `IDictionary.ContainsKey(<value>)` test

really step by step, but I think this makes things clearer at first.

```
//left part of lambda, p
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
//right part
//p.Attributes
Expression left = Expression.Property(parameter, "Attributes");

var method = typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).GetMethod("ContainsKey");
//p.Attributes.ContainsKey("Brand");
Expression containsExpression = Expression.Call(left, method, Expression.Constant(attribute));
//p.Attributes.Item["Brand"]
Expression keyExpression= Expression.Property(left, "Item", new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(attribute) });
//"Tyco"
var right = Expression.Constant(value);
//{p => IIF(p.Attributes.ContainsKey("Brand"), (p.Attributes.Item["Brand"] == "Tyco"), False)}
Expression operation = Expression.Condition(
                           containsExpression,
                           Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType[op], keyExpression, right), 
                           Expression.Constant(false));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(operation, parameter);
```

Comment: No. Brand is a key in the Attributes dictionary. The Attributes dictionary is a property on the Product.

Comment: @JohnKraft so a version with the ContainsKey test.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out how to get the Index as a property expression. I didn't realize that I could make a property expression from another property expression. The reassignment of left to the indexer property expression was the only part I was missing in my code.

Comment: BTW, the indexer doesn't always have to be called `Item`. For example, for `string`, it's called [`Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx). But this code will work fine for `Dictionary` or `IDictionary`.

Comment: @svick Right, thanks. Is get_item more "generic", then ? Or not ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Nope, the getter for `string.Chars` is called `get_Chars`. I think the most generic way would be to use [`GetDefaultMembers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getdefaultmembers.aspx).

Comment: @svick that what I was suspecting (could have read the doc, by the way)... But I discovered `GetDefaultMembers()` (shame maybe, anyway, good to know).