# I can't seem to be able to access a Dictonary<string, object> values while building a dynamic linq expression

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, expression-trees

I'm trying to generate a linq expression in asp.net core for MongoDB using the MongoDriver and I can't access the runtime value of a dictonary with the expression generator. Thanks in advance!

```
private Expression<Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>> GenerateWhereExpression(Dictionary<string, object> filterParams)
{
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), "x");
    var dictPropery = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, "name"); // Dictonary value with respect to the name key
    var methodCall = Expression.Call(dictPropery, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), Expression.Constant(filterParams["name"], typeof(string)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>>(methodCall, pe);
    return lambda;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is the where clause of the query to get all the data for a report.

Expresssiom, that should be created as result of the method should look like:

```
x => ((string)x["name"]).Contains(term)
```

Comment: your `.Call` is using the `MethodInfo` from `string`.

Comment: write plain c# code that you aim to generate like `x.Keys[0].Contains("a")`

Comment: Could you explain, what do you want to achieve? I don't understand it, and i don't see how it could be used for mongodb query

Comment: @MaksimSimkin Yes! I'm trying to generate the where clause of my query which is a IQueryable<Dictonary<string, object>> but when i try to access the Dictonary value I get a value null error.

Comment: @AndoniZubizarreta  How should this clause look like? You want to give it to Find method of the driver? Do you query your mongodb as a collection of dictionary<string, object>?   Don't you want to deserialize results to model classes?

Comment: @MaksimSimkin x => ((string)x["name"]).Contains(term) (I'm sorry I should included this in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you need to change your method this way:

```
private Expression<Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>> 
                     GenerateWhereExpression(Dictionary<string, object> filterParams)
{
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), "x");
    // it is call of x.getItem("name") what is the same as x["name"]
    var dictPropery = Expression.Call(pe, 
           typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod("get_Item"), 
           Expression.Constant("name")); 

    //cast to ((string)x.getItem("name"))
    var castProperty = Expression.Convert(dictPropery, typeof(string));
    var methodCall = Expression.Call(castProperty, 
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), 
                    Expression.Constant(filterParams["name"], typeof(string)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>>(methodCall, pe);
    return lambda;
}
```

I have tested it with my mongodriver and it seems to work.
Actually, for getting Items from dictionary you need to call `Item` property ([Building Expression Tree Using a Parameter's Indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663345/building-expression-tree-using-a-parameters-indexer)). But either i have used it wrong way, or MongoDb driver couldn't translate it properly, so i am doing it calling `get_Item` method, what is the same thing.